# What order does Grails evaluate its dependency repositories?

Tags: maven, grails, grails-plugin, grails-config

**Does Grails evaluate its Maven repos top-down or bottom-up?**

I would assume top-down but some manual testing might indicate bottom-up. I can provide test results if need be.

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    repositories {
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```